# How to say "I mean" or "rather" in the sense of "that's what I meant to say"?

Tags: vocabulaire

If you misspoke, you might then correct yourself with the addition of "I mean" or "rather." E.g.:

> Je veux des bœufs. Des œufs, I mean. (or) Des œufs, rather.

How would that be said?

Comment: Ou plutôt, I'd say.

Comment: As in "Je veux des boeufs. Ou plutôt, des oeufs." ?

Comment: If you used the wrong word: *Je veux des bœufs. Heu.. des œufs, je veux dire*; if you changed your mind: as Luke wrote *Je veux des bœufs. Des œufs, plutôt.* or *Je veux des bœufs, ou plutôt des œufs.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si tu veux te reprendre après une erreur, "Je veux dire" fonctionne bien.

> Je veux des bœufs. Euh, des œufs, je veux dire.